# Why my S3 device sounds when magnetic card is put on its back?

Tags: applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my Galaxy S3 make a noise when I put it down?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25584/why-does-my-galaxy-s3-make-a-noise-when-i-put-it-down)

Why my samsung S3 play a sound when I put above my gym magnetic card? Only with this card the device play this type of sound. Nothing happen if I put it above credit card or other magnetic/chip support.
The gym card open doors and let me enter inside the gym if I've paid. There's a way (maybe an app) to read what happen when my s3 grab that card?

Comment: NFC, most likely.

Comment: Can you better define ***magnetic card***?

Comment: You were right. For magnetic card I mean a card with a band all along the card, in opposition to chip card i.e. a card with a single chip on it.
My gym card doesn't have a chip (or at least I haven't found it), so it's more likely that this is a magnetic one (even if I can't see a sort of magnetic bar).

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [Why does my Galaxy S3 make a noise when I put it down?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25584)

Comment: Yes, it's duplicate. Confirmed that I want something to read data above card and data exchanged between devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your S3 has an [NFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication) chip in it that can read and write NFC tags which are a type of RFID. RFID is most commonly used for things like identification chips for dogs and NFC for public transport payment cards like Octopus or Oyster. It's also in quite a lot of credit and debit cards now too.

The card will have some kind of tag in it - the [NXP TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite) app will give you information about what kind of tag it is.